# jQuery AJAX Does Not Seem to Fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have searched as much as I can throughout here and elsewhere trying to solve this; I can't seem to find something similar enough. The button click fires as it prints to the console. However, every console response I ask for afterwards does not happen, leading me to believe that the AJAX call itself is not firing.

```
<form type="GET" action="/api.php" id="search" name="search">
  <label for="getICAO">Search by ICAO:</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="getICAO" name="getICAO" placeholder="KLAX"><br />
  <label for="getCity">Search by city:</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="getCity" name="getCity"> <br />
  <label for="button"><input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Find Airport"> </label><br />
</form>

<script>
jQuery("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');
    // This part works ^

    // I have verified that the variables are passed to the PHP file. The PHP file is 
    //functioning properly and the database query returns with JSON formatted results.
    var getICAO = jQuery("#getICAO").val();
    var getCity = jQuery("#getCity").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api.php?getICAO="+getICAO+"&getCity="+getCity,
      dataType: "json",

    }) .done(function(data) {

            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            jQuery.each(result, function(key, value) {
               console.log(result); // Nothing returns
      });
   })     
});

</script>
```

This is likely a simple error that I just don't understand. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried checking the console for errors? There is a comma after `dataType: "json"` with no trailing element - this looks suspicious.

Comment: Is the trailing element what was posted below with the data:{ } bit?

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` will throw an error because the response is already parsed due to `dataType: 'json'`. As above, check your browser's developer console for errors

Comment: I commented out the jQuery.parseJSON(data) and added a console.log(data) in place of the variable declaration and nothing prints to the console. It also does not throw any errors. It only says "submitted" from the console.log function after the button click.

Comment: _"It also does not throw any errors"_  you don't have any error handler to report them. You can add `.fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => console.error(textStatus, errorThrown))`. You can also check your browser's _Network_ console to see the requests and responses

Comment: Thank you. I added this, found an error, and fixed the error. Now the data is returning in the console which is good, except I'm not sure how to show only the data that I want on the screen. I understand how to print the data, but in the each loop it only displays the last row of data and I need the first.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I don't know if the code here is every thing or just the form

anyway Jquery is a javascript library and you have to reference it in the head of every page you want to use Jquery ( or in the body doesn't matter a lot)

you can download it or use the CDN:

https://jquery.com/download/

and you don't have to set *action* and *method* for the html *form*

because you are already preventing Default

also it's better to let ajax handle the GET parameters,
like This:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api.php",
    data: {
        getICAO: getICAO,
        getCity: getCity
    },
    dataType: "json"
})
```

**here is the working page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="search" name="search">
        <label for="getICAO">Search by ICAO:</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="getICAO" name="getICAO" placeholder="KLAX"><br />
        <label for="getCity">Search by city:</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="getCity" name="getCity"> <br />
        <label for="button"><input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Find Airport"> </label><br />
    </form>


    <script>
        jQuery("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('submitted');
            // This part works ^

            // I have verified that the variables are passed to the PHP file. The PHP file is 
            //functioning properly and the database query returns with JSON formatted results.
            var getICAO = jQuery("#getICAO").val();
            var getCity = jQuery("#getCity").val();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api.php",
                data: {
                    getICAO: getICAO,
                    getCity: getCity
                },
            dataType: "json"

            })
            .done(function(data) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                jQuery.each(result, function(key, value) {
                    console.log(result); // Nothing returns
                });
            })     
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. A few notes which are probably helpful that I should have specified from the start. I am using WordPress so jQuery is already installed. Could you explain what you mean by letting AJAX handle the GET parameters? This is all of the code on this page, the PHP file it references works.

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` is unnecessary and will probably throw an error

Comment: I went ahead and commented that out but there is nothing printing to the console beyond the "submitted" after the click event. So the click event fires but I'm not sure it's linking to the PHP file. Separately, the PHP does work as I've tested it independently.

Comment: what i meant with letting AJAX handle the GET parameters it's the code right after that